# JPA package name / structure - does it matter

Tags: java, jpa, orm, entitymanager

I have a class Comm in a package called com.dto.testkk. I have another class Cntc that is in a package called com.dto.needsWork. Each of these maps to a corresponding table in a database, with Comm containing Cntc_id as it's foreign key.

The issue I am facing is if I refactor Comm into com.dto package, then for some reason delete in the table (using EntityMgr:remove) is no longer working. I keep getting a "No Data Found" error. Create and Update works perfectly. Nothing else has changed except the package name. I have updated the ORM.xml files as well as the persistence.xml files that contain the mappings to these ORM files appropriately.

This issue happens if I refactor Comm to any package that alphabetically precedes needsWork! If I refactor to (say) com.dto.omg it works, but not if it's com.dto.mgo

I have no idea why this is happening. Any insights greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I got this working, but still don't understand the underlying issue. 
What I did as follows:

Original Code:

```
private void delete(){
contacts.forEach(
contact ->
{
   JpaHelper.execResultListQuery(
   em,
   ALL_COMMS_BY_CONTACT_QUERY,
   Comm.class,
   contact.getId()).forEach(em::remove);

   em.remove(contact);

});
em.flush();
}
```

The above code works when they are in the original packages mentioned (Comm in testkk and Cntc in needsWork). With the changed package structure, the exception was thrown at em.flush() with data not found. I think for some reason Contact was flushed before Comm and hence this is happening. Though I do not know why.

Change to code to make it to work now:

```
private void delete(){
contacts.forEach(
contact ->
{
   JpaHelper.execResultListQuery(
   em,
   ALL_COMMS_BY_CONTACT_QUERY,
   Comm.class,
   contact.getId()).forEach(em::remove);
   em.flush();
   em.remove(contact);
   em.flush();
});
}
```

Thank you
Karthik